# En un documento civil, ¿qué significa "Enmendado- [cualquier palabra]-vale.-"?

Tags: vocabulario-técnico, lenguaje-jurídico

En la última parte de esta acta de nacimiento, ¿qué significa lo siguiente?

> Enmendado- corriente-vale.-

Supongo que el documento ha sido revisado o corregido, pero ¿qué significa el resto?

[image]

Comment: Había que ver el documento para ver a que corrección se refiere. En algunos documentos, cuando se hace una corrección ponían "digo" y a continuación el texto correcto. De ahí lo de "Cuando digo digo, digo Diego"

Comment: Ah, qué tonto soy.  Gracias a su ejemplo, me di cuenta de una sobreescritura en la palabra "corriente" en el texto del documento.  Entonces, la dicha anotación significa que la palabra correcta es "corriente", ¿verdad?

Comment: Tiene la misma validez legal la palabra "Vale" si es puesta antes de la correccion? Ejemplo" Entre lineas vale: "...........""" o necesariamente tiene que ir al final de la correccion como normalmente se hace???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Los documentos públicos tienen valor legal y son, por lo tanto, inviolables.

Cuando no existía la computadora y los documentos se escribían a máquina o inclusive a mano, era usual que, durante el tipeo o la escritura, o al momento de la firma, se detectaran errores que se debían subsanar antes de la formalización del documento.

En ocasiones, se utilizaba goma de borrar, corrector líquido, o inclusive una hoja de afeitar a fin de raspar la palabra o letra equivocada, para luego introducir la palabra correcta.

En la práctica de los escribanos, la norma dice que debe colocarse:

1) La acción realizada

2) La palabra o frase corregida (que se puede escribir a máquina o a mano), normalmente entre comillas

3) La palabra "vale" (que significa que lo agregado es válido, o sea, tiene fuerza legal y no debe considerarse como una adulteración del documento)

Es probable que en el documento en cuestión haya una letra de más, por ejemplo, que diga "corrientes", y se haya tachado la "s", o que se haya borrado una palabra y se haya sobrescrito "corriente". Encontramos así:

```
1) Enmendado 2) "corriente" 3) Vale => Enmendado "corriente" vale
```

Nota: Ahora que se ha agregado el documento, puede observarse que la "e" interna de "corriente" está como duplicada, como producto de un segundo golpe de la máquina de escribir, lo cual podría causar cierta confusión. Esto justifica que se haya decidido salvar la palabra, a fin de disipar cualquier duda.

También se puede encontrar:

```
Sobre raspado XXX vale
```

Otra posibilidad es que se escriba entre líneas, y así tenemos:

```
Entre líneas XXX vale
```

Importante: Antes de las firmas, debe aparecer la firma del funcionario (ej. un escribano o un traductor) inmediatamente después de las correcciones realizadas, como avalando su legalidad.

Inclusive en estos tiempos en que todos los documentos se escriben en computadora y se imprimen, puede ocurrir que al momento de la firma haya que salvar un error y no se cuente con una impresora cerca o con tiempo para reimprimir, en cuyo caso son aceptables las prácticas comentadas.

Comment: Por tanto, "enmendado [palabra] vale" quiere decir que "palabra" vale y debe tenerse en cuenta. ¡Qué bueno! Gran respuesta, me encantó aprenderlo.